# Merge json from array and then recreate array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array as follows

```
Array
(
    [photo] => Array
        (
            [0] => {"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "content_type": "image/jpeg", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699176"}
            [1] => {"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "sha256" : "7e5bdd023b6cf21efe42a8ec90bc1993fc853980d4b564688e5ac2d28c64223c" , "size" : "777835"}
            [2] => {"file_name":"sample.png", "content_type": "image/png", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699177"}
            [3] => {"file_name":"sample.png", "sha256" : "e6aa1bf1cdb7ca546576cecd61973939be4f1dc8cec3a4f3b49b31d8f60e202f" , "size" : "278383"}
        )

    [submit] => Upload
)
```

I want to create an array as follows

```
Array
(
    [photo] => Array
        (
            [0] => {"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "content_type": "image/jpeg", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699176" , "sha256" : "7e5bdd023b6cf21efe42a8ec90bc1993fc853980d4b564688e5ac2d28c64223c" , "size" : "777835"}

            [1] => {"file_name":"sample.png", "content_type": "image/png", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699177" , "sha256" : "e6aa1bf1cdb7ca546576cecd61973939be4f1dc8cec3a4f3b49b31d8f60e202f" , "size" : "278383"}
        )

    [submit] => Upload
)
```

Comment: Do they always come in ordered pairs like your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to build a map with decoded JSON objects, keyed by their *file_name* values, and then applies [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to convert the objects in that map back to JSON strings.

The intermediate [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) turns the associative array into an indexed array:

```
$data['photo'] = array_map('json_encode', array_values(array_reduce($data['photo'], 
    function($dict, $json) {
        $obj = json_decode($json, true);
        $key = $obj['file_name'];
        if (!isset($dict[$key])) $dict[$key] = [];
        $dict[$key] += $obj; // merging arrays with plus operator
        return $dict;
    }, []))
);
```

This solution does not necessitate that two related JSON strings are consecutive. It will work if the array is in any order. It also works if there would be more than two JSON strings with the same `file_name` property, joining whatever other properties are in those extra JSON strings.

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/586973).

Comment: Nice one thing though. The resulting array is multi-demiensional. It would be okay if its indexed

Comment: Thanks, @Abiodun, I added an intermediate call to `array_values` to turn the associative array into an indexed array.

Comment: Exactly what i needed...Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = ['photo'=>
    ['{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "content_type": "image/jpeg", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699176"}','{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "sha256" : "7e5bdd023b6cf21efe42a8ec90bc1993fc853980d4b564688e5ac2d28c64223c" , "size" : "777835"}','{"file_name":"sample.png", "content_type": "image/png", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699177"}','{"file_name":"sample.png", "sha256" : "e6aa1bf1cdb7ca546576cecd61973939be4f1dc8cec3a4f3b49b31d8f60e202f" , "size" : "278383"}'],

    'submit'=> 'Upload'];
```

// This is your given array

```
$result_array = [
    'photos' => [],
    'submit' => 'Upload'
    ];
for($i=0; $i < count($array['photo'])-1; $i++){
    $array_one = json_decode($array['photo'][$i], true);
    $array_two = json_decode($array['photo'][$i++], true);
        array_push($result_array['photos'], array_merge($array_one, $array_two));
}
print_r($result_array);
```

Comment: The two arrays are always the same. You probably wanted `++$i` instead of `$i++`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'photo' => array(
                '0' => '{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "content_type": "image/jpeg", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699176"}',
                '1' => '{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "sha256" : "7e5bdd023b6cf21efe42a8ec90bc1993fc853980d4b564688e5ac2d28c64223c" , "size" : "777835"}',
                '4' => '{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "content_type": "image/jpeg", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699176"}',
                '2' => '{"file_name":"sample.png", "content_type": "image/png", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699177"}',
                '3' => '{"file_name":"sample.png", "sha256" : "e6aa1bf1cdb7ca546576cecd61973939be4f1dc8cec3a4f3b49b31d8f60e202f" , "size" : "278383"}',
            ),
    'submit' => 'Upload'
); // Your array representation

function distinct($item, $key, $array) {
    $file_name = json_decode($item)->file_name; // saving file name
    $find_count = 0; // initializing found count
    
    foreach($array['photo'] as $i => $json) {
        $json = json_decode($json);
        
        if($json->file_name == $file_name) {
            if($find_count >= 1) {
                unset($array['photo'][$i]);
            }
            if(property_exists($json, 'content_type')) { // This keep the json with a content type property
                $find_count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($array['photo'], 'distinct', $array);

var_dump($array);

?>
```

This works on php 7, tested on [sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8749cf59ed0275c8068b78b60a8c5634aa106e3f):

I hope this helped you, instead this could inspired you and other.

Comment: Values are lost with this code. Where did `"sha256"` go? You need to *merge* entries, not *unset* them.

Comment: You're rigth @trincot, didn't see merging effect. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Structure**

```
[
    'photo'  => [
        '0' => '{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "content_type": "image/jpeg", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699176"}',
        '1' => '{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "sha256" : "7e5bdd023b6cf21efe42a8ec90bc1993fc853980d4b564688e5ac2d28c64223c" , "size" : "777835"}',
        '4' => '{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "content_type": "image/jpeg", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699176"}',
        '2' => '{"file_name":"sample.png", "content_type": "image/png", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699177"}',
        '3' => '{"file_name":"sample.png", "sha256" : "e6aa1bf1cdb7ca546576cecd61973939be4f1dc8cec3a4f3b49b31d8f60e202f" , "size" : "278383"}',
    ],
    'submit' => 'Upload'
];
```

**Desired Output**

```
[
    [photo] => [
        [0] => {"file_name":"Penguins.jpg","content_type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_path":"\/var\/www\/servergreek.com\/public_html\/www\/imgscript\/tmp\/0048699176","sha256":"7e5bdd023b6cf21efe42a8ec90bc1993fc853980d4b564688e5ac2d28c64223c","size":"777835"}
        [1] => {"file_name":"sample.png","content_type":"image\/png","tmp_path":"\/var\/www\/servergreek.com\/public_html\/www\/imgscript\/tmp\/0048699177","sha256":"e6aa1bf1cdb7ca546576cecd61973939be4f1dc8cec3a4f3b49b31d8f60e202f","size":"278383"}
    ]
    [submit] => Upload
]
```

**Code**

```
    <?php
    $array = getYourArrayStrcuture(); // you don't need this as you already have this array strcuture
    $photoByName = getArrayByFileName($array); // Get array back with file name as key
    $result = convertArrayToJson($photoByName,$array); // convert array to json
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);

    /**
     * Convert array to json
     */
    function convertArrayToJson($photoByName,$array)
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach($photoByName as $key=>$value){
            $result[] = json_encode($value);
        }
        $array['photo'] = $result;
        return $array;
    }

    /**
     * Get array back with file name as key
     */
    function getArrayByFileName($array)
    {
        $photoArray = $array['photo'];
        $photoByName = [];

        foreach ($photoArray as $photo) {
            $itemJsonToArray = json_decode($photo, true);
            if (!isset($photoByName[ $itemJsonToArray['file_name'] ])) {
                $photoByName[ $itemJsonToArray['file_name'] ] = $itemJsonToArray;
            } else {
                $photoByName[ $itemJsonToArray['file_name'] ] = array_merge($photoByName[ $itemJsonToArray['file_name'] ], $itemJsonToArray);
            }
        }

        return $photoByName;
    }

    /**
     * You don't need this as you already have this array structure
     */
    function getYourArrayStrcuture()
    {
        $yourArrayStructure = [
            'photo'  => [
                '0' => '{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "content_type": "image/jpeg", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699176"}',
                '1' => '{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "sha256" : "7e5bdd023b6cf21efe42a8ec90bc1993fc853980d4b564688e5ac2d28c64223c" , "size" : "777835"}',
                '4' => '{"file_name":"Penguins.jpg", "content_type": "image/jpeg", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699176"}',
                '2' => '{"file_name":"sample.png", "content_type": "image/png", "tmp_path": "/var/www/servergreek.com/public_html/www/imgscript/tmp/0048699177"}',
                '3' => '{"file_name":"sample.png", "sha256" : "e6aa1bf1cdb7ca546576cecd61973939be4f1dc8cec3a4f3b49b31d8f60e202f" , "size" : "278383"}',
            ],
            'submit' => 'Upload'
        ];

        return $yourArrayStructure;
    }
?>
```